# OpenGL 3.x core sampler2DRect (GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE) example

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, opengl-3

I'm trying to figure out how to make a semi-transparent 2D overlay over my 3D scene, reading the OpenGL SuperBible 5th edition for reference.

It has an example which overlays the OpenGL logo over a scene (in Chapter 7) using the texture target GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, and a GLSL uniform type called sampler2DRect. The texture is supposed to be displayed in the fragment shader using the texture() command.

The example in this book uses many source files and I'm having a really hard time implementing it in a simple program, so I'm wondering if anyone could point me to a simpler example of the sampler2DRect.

I have no trouble with the part about switching to an orthographic projection, rather when I try to load the texture, it just displays the surface in white. My code's getting really messy at this point, and I can't seem to pinpoint the problem, so I'd rather start over from scratch following a simpler example if one is available anywhere.

P.S. I'm using SFML 2.0rc for loading the image file, in case it matters.

Comment: This is not really an appropriate place to ask for tutorials (google would probably serve you better), though if you'd like to salvage what you've got feel free to add your code to this post. In my experience white textures are generally attributed to a couple different mistakes and not that difficult to debug. Have you tried glGetError as well?

Comment: I've been looking on google for over a week and I can't find anything. Haven't tried glGetError() yet, but I will now that you've suggested it. I'm not opposed to sharing my code, I just think it may be too much for anyone to reasonably look through at this point. I was mainly hoping someone could recommend another textbook with a simpler example, or some online example that's hiding from google... Thanks for the response, I won't throw out the code yet since you say white textures tend to be simple to debug!

Comment: Hmm... something in my render function is causing GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Comment: For some reason GL_INVALID_OPERATION is being set after I call glUseProgram() in my shader handler... I tried moving the call around to different places, but it's not fixing the error.

Comment: Have you checked your shaders to make sure they compile and link successfully? Check out GL_COMPILE_STATUS and GL_LINK_STATUS of glGetShaderiv and glGetProgramiv after compiling and linking, respectfully. Also see glGetShaderInfoLog and glGetProgramInfoLog.

Comment: These functions you're talking about are very useful! I just wish I knew how to interpret the output... Shader compiling and linking are returning 0, and glGetShaderInfoLog is returning length of 0, but glGetProgramInfoLog returns this (which I don't understand):

Comment: Vertex info
-----------
0(39) : error C1101: ambiguous overloaded function reference "mul(mat4, vec3)"
    (0) : mat3x4 mul(mat3x1, mat1x4)
    (0) : mat3 mul(mat3x1, mat1x3)
    (0) : mat3x2 mul(mat3x1, mat1x2)
    (0) : mat3x1 mul(mat3x1, mat1)
    (0) : mat2x4 mul(mat2x1, mat1x4)
    (0) : mat2x3 mul(mat2x1, mat1x3)
    (0) : mat2 mul(mat2x1, mat1x2)
    (0) : mat2x1 mul(mat2x1, mat1)
    (0) : mat1x4 mul(mat1x3, mat3x4)
    (0) : mat1x3 mul(mat1x3, mat3)
    (0) : mat1x2 mul(mat1x3, mat3x2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
error C1101: ambiguous overloaded function reference "mul(mat4, vec3)" 
     (0) : mat3x4 mul(mat3x1, mat1x4)
     (0) : mat3 mul(mat3x1, mat1x3) 
     (0) : mat3x2 mul(mat3x1, mat1x2) 
     (0) : mat3x1 mul(mat3x1, mat1) 
     (0) : mat2x4 mul(mat2x1, mat1x4) 
     .....
```

This is a very wordy way to tell you that there's no such function that multiplies a `mat4` with a `vec3`. It's then listing all of the legal variants of `mul`.

Your dimensions must match when you multiply matrices, what you likely want is to multiply a `mat4` with a **`vec4`**. If this is for your position coordinate, then add a `1.0` as the final value of the vector:

```
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
in vec3 position;

main()
   gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

Comment: Thanks, doing that causes the glGetShaderiv() and glGetProgramiv() to return 1 (I guess 1 is GL_TRUE), and causes the Info Logs to return zero length, however, it seems that calling glGetShaderInfoLog() trips a 502 error (the 502 isn't happening when calling glUseProgram anymore now that the shaders are fixed). A side effect of all this is now my white square has disappeared... I'm not giving up yet, and I'll keep messing around until anyone has anymore ideas. Thanks for helping me through this Tim!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tim's answer, make sure that :

- Your texture is bound : glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
- The vertex shader outputs UV coords : out vec2 UV;
- The vertex shader gets UV coords : in vec2 UV;
- The VBO with the UVs exists, is enabled, bound and set ( glEnableVertexAttribArray, glBindBuffer, glVertexAttribPointer )
- glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

And special items for rectangle textures :

- The UV coords are in [0,width]x[0,height] (special case for rectangle textures).
- Make sure that your quad has approx. the same size as the texture ( rect.tex don't have mipmaps)
- Use standard textures instead. They can be NPOT.

Also : use gDebugger.

Comment: Thanks Calvin, my texture is displaying now, but on a white surface... My goal is for the surface to be transparent instead of white (the texture image uses alpha transparency), so do I need to send some color data to one of the shaders to change the surface from white to transparent? The problem causing my texture to not display before, turned out to be that I was using glBindAttribLocation() with the number 0 for my vertices, and with number 2 for the texture coords, but I wasn't using the number 1 for anything. So having an unused number in between made it not display.

Comment: Alright, it's all working properly after sending some color data to the shaders (with an alpha value of 0.0). Yay! Thanks Tim and Calvin1602!!